# What material pipe to carry water to a detached garage

Tags: water, pipe, pex, underground, detached-structure

Location: California.
The water service to my house arrives with some sort of plastic material pipe (I would assume this is the original material used in the 70s when this house was built).

I now plan to build a detached garage that will have a bathroom. The distance to the main water pipe is around 100ft. What pipe material can I use to carry water to the new detached structure? I checked at the supply house and they suggest I use copper coil. Pretty expensive solution but the problem is that they do not have it in stock.

I looked into PEX but it seems in California it cannot be buried directly. I could certainly consider putting it into conduit, is it acceptable?

I have read online (and according to my interpretation of the code it should be acceptable) that PE-4710 High Density Polyethylene is a candidate, but it's not exactly easy to find it.

What is my best option here? Thanks.

Comment: Copper seems totally over-kill to me and like you said, very expensive. Check around at some of the big box stores and supply houses, get a few opinions. You may also want to check with your local inspector (AHJ) Codes vary by location, so it's hard for us to give good advice.

Comment: I did that kind of research, it's oddly difficult to find a reputable source that knows what they are talking about. I spoke to the inspector at my previous (waste water) inspection and he merely confirmed that PEX is not allowed for direct burial, unfortunately he did not give any other advice.

Comment: Checked the place I bought my pump from (online water supplies site) and the well pipe is PE-4710. I won't take this to the point of spamming for a particular supplier, but not that hard at all.

Comment: I am not aware of any restrictions on posting links on this website
For example, a seller that I successfully used in the past https://www.supplyhouse.com/Oil-Creek-ABT21010-1-Blue-Aqua-Jet-CTS-Water-Service-Poly-Pipe-PE-4710-250-PSI-100-ft-Coil the item is backordered and the date indicated is bogus, as it's been like that since August. I will try others

Comment: Feels spammy/shilly to me, but it was aquascience.net I looked at.

Answer (score 8):

I don't know California specifics, but "Polyethylene well water pipe" is a common material for direct burial installation - get the 200 PSI version for the thickest walls / most durability.

Quick look at an online supplier finds (no shock) that the 160 & 200 PSI well water pipe is PE 4710 resin high density PE. Thus, not so hard to find.

If direct burial is the stumbling block, put in a sleeve and use PEX if want to use PEX and can't find an appropriate product to your local codes.

Comment: Hello, would you be so kind to give me a link to such online vendor? Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Ask the supply house if they have a waterworks division or if they can give the name of a local waterworks distributor. (Ferguson is a national waterworks distributor who happens to have branches in a few California cities, for example.) You may be more likely to find the HDPE tubing through waterworks channels rather than traditional plumbing/building supply houses.

You'll need to get a steel insert and brass compression to pipe thread adapter to use at each end of the HDPE tube. They may also ask whether you want CTS or IPS (copper tube size or iron pipe size). From what I know CTS is more common, but the reality is it won't make much difference for you so long as you buy tube and fittings all using the same sizing scheme.

Comment: A little update: the local WHCI sent me to a Ferguson waterworks indeded. Most people there had no idea what HDPE pipe even was, thinking that I needed corrugated for drainage applications. Finally they asked a more knowledgeable person and he was extremely gracious in explaining most applications for buried water service in the area use SDR-9 HDPE pipe in CTS size; IPS is apparently more common in the East. He also showed me some very expensive looking fittings for it.

Comment: Unfortunately, they do not have any pipe in stock, and even if they did they wouldn't be able to sell it to me because they are prevented from creating new accounts. A trick could be to call a salesman at the phone that would be using a dummy account, collect my payment, and then place the order for me but so far I wasn't successful in contacting a sales representative willing to do so.

Comment: I've been meaning to open an account with Ferguson for a while now - going to be needing some SDR-35 sewer pipe soon. So I tried creating an account on their web site yesterday. It took about 4 hours from requesting the account until it was approved; now I can see a few thousand 100 ft coils of 3/4 and 1 inch CTS SDR 9 tube at my local branch, and there's a nice little "add to cart" button on the screen. Also found the CTS x FIP brass couplings for adapting that tube to pipe thread. :-)

Comment: I tried to open an account online as soon as I read you message; I received an automated email right away they received the application but now it's been several days and there is no followup. Did you request as a private individual, do you have a company...?

Comment: @AlessioSangalli Yes I requested an account in the name of my company. As an alternative, if you know any general contractor (especially the kind who develops subdivisions), excavator, or plumber, you might try asking if they could order the items for you.